# Oracle SQL - Use coalesce when results is empty

Tags: sql, oracle

My query return different number of results eg.

```
Select ename from emp where job = 'MANAGER'; -- 3 rows
```

BLAKE
CLARK
JONES

```
Select ename from emp where job = 'ABC';  -- 0 rows
```

When use:

```
Select coalesce(max(ename),'-1') from emp where job = 'MANAGER';
```

Only return JONES,  Is it possible return all
BLAKE
CLARK
JONES when result is not empty if empty return -1

Comment: Please share the table structure so we can assist better. It is hard to troubleshoot without knowing how the data exists in the database. Also, please provide an example result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you already asked this question few minutes ago.

Comment: @EJ Egyed  This is default emp table  https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_O5AEB2HE08PYEPTGCFLZU9YCV.html

Comment: @SalmanA  This question is different!

Comment: No it isn't. You merely forgot to specify that the result could be more than one row.

Comment: @SalmanA . . . The question was different.  In the previous question, the filtering was on `empno` and there was good reason to assume that would return at most one row.  That is not the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use lateral join for this task. Put `coalesce` wherever you need.

> ```
> select
>   s.*
> from dual
>   left join lateral (
>     select *
>     from emp
>     where job = 'MANAGER'
>   ) s
>     on 1 = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> EMPNO | ENAME | JOB     |  MGR | HIREDATE  |  SAL | COMM | DEPTNO
> ----: | :---- | :------ | ---: | :-------- | ---: | ---: | -----:
>  7698 | BLAKE | MANAGER | 7839 | 01-MAY-81 | 2850 | null |     30
>  7782 | CLARK | MANAGER | 7839 | 09-JUN-81 | 2450 | null |     10
>  7566 | JONES | MANAGER | 7839 | 02-APR-81 | 2975 | null |     20
> ```

> ```
> select
>   s.*
> from dual
>   left join lateral (
>     select *
>     from emp
>     where job = 'MANAGER__'
>   ) s
>     on 1 = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> EMPNO | ENAME | JOB  |  MGR | HIREDATE |  SAL | COMM | DEPTNO
> ----: | :---- | :--- | ---: | :------- | ---: | ---: | -----:
>  null | null  | null | null | null     | null | null |   null
> ```

**EDIT**: But keep in mind, that `comm` is `null` in normal data, so plain `coalesce` may break your original data. You need to use some join indicator to check if the data was joined or not. Below is updated (bulky) code.

> ```
> select
>   decode(flag, 1, empno, -1) as empno,
>   decode(flag, 1, ename, 'Default ENAME') as ename,
>   decode(flag, 1, job, 'Default JOB') as job,
>   decode(flag, 1, mgr, -1) as mgr,
>   decode(flag, 1, hiredate, date '1000-01-01') as hiredate,
>   decode(flag, 1, sal, -1) as sal,
>   decode(flag, 1, comm, -1) as comm,
>   decode(flag, 1, deptno, -1) as deptno
> from dual
>   left join lateral (
>     select emp.*, 1 as flag
>     from emp
>     where emp.job = 'MANAGER__'
>   ) s
>     on 1 = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> EMPNO | ENAME         | JOB         | MGR | HIREDATE   | SAL | COMM | DEPTNO
> ----: | :------------ | :---------- | --: | :--------- | --: | ---: | -----:
>    -1 | Default ENAME | Default JOB |  -1 | 1000-01-01 |  -1 |   -1 |     -1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a7f96320652f1b1ea8c085bb73a0b63f)*

Comment: @user_odoo Welcome. But be careful, as `comm`, for example, is null in normal data. So correct way will be to add some dummy flag to check if something was joined. I've edited my answer